# textFieldDidEndEditing not working in tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitextfield

I have a `tableview` with multiple number of `section` and `rows`.

Each row has a `textField`, the problem is I want to save the text of the `textField` in a `dictionary` with its tag as key and `textfield` text as value.

I want to save it as soon as user touches somewhere else (or if possible when user stopped typing). I used  `textFieldDidEndEditing` but it didn't work.

I declared "`textfield.delegate=self`" in `cellForRowAt` delegate function. is it wrong? what should I do?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show me your code?

Comment: textFieldDidEndEditing would work for this, but like @JogendarChoudhary said, we can't help you without code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the question is missing some information, but you can detect if the textField `textFieldDidEndEditing` using two ways:

**First Way**) As you did, in `cellForRowAt`

```
textField.delegate = self
```

and make sure the view controller conform the protocol UITextFieldDelegate this way

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
   func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
       print(textField.tag, " -> ", textField.text)
   }
}
```

**Second Way**) Right click on the textField on the storyboard and drag from Event (Editing Did End) to the class file of the cell

See the below screenshot for the both ways

[image]